# IIS problem, web application

Tags: iis, recycle

When I use the web application, the application logs me out. I think it might be an IIS recycle.

EventViewer Message:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4927 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEF582FA42) (80131506)
----------

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.4927, time stamp: 0x4a27466f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000006be81f
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13

-------------
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 7.5.7600.16385
P3: 4a5bd0eb
P4: mscorwks.dll
P5: 2.0.50727.4927
P6: 4a27466f
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000006be81f
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_6a41af6fc5f73afd65a4b62225f4f0ff51ba820_60e9d666

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: d745615a-e67c-11df-83c0-d8d385b73c58
Report Status: 4
```

I analyzed the crash dump with windbg but I dont know how can I solve and what is problem:

```
0:056> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\mscorlib\9a017aa8d51322f18a40f414fa35872d\mscorlib.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Web.RegularE#\bf11731ff6e75c72e9939a05151e7484\System.Web.RegularExpressions.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Web.RegularExpressions.ni.dll
Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Web\d753bba0990df9a19883f05d5b681d3b\System.Web.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Web.ni.dll
Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Data\46a0336046744a9f29986b208b8d38d4\System.Data.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Data.ni.dll
Unable to load image C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7600.16385_none_2b4f45e87195fcc4\GdiPlus.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for GdiPlus.dll
Unable to load image C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System\247913fa7ae6fcf04ea33d28d24ab611\System.ni.dll, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
GetPageUrlData failed, server returned HTTP status 500
URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/w3wp_exe/7_5_7600_16385/4a5bd0eb/mscorwks_dll/2_0_50727_4927/4a27466f/c0000005/006be81f.htm?Retriage=1

FAULTING_IP: 
mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+24f
000007fe`f5dde81f 418b4514        mov     eax,dword ptr [r13+14h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef5dde81f (mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+0x000000000000024f)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000014
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000014

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000014

READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000014 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+24f
000007fe`f5dde81f 418b4514        mov     eax,dword ptr [r13+14h]

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

MANAGED_BITNESS_MISMATCH: 
Managed code needs matching platform of sos.dll for proper analysis. Use 'x64' debugger.

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fef3a0bf50 to 000007fef5dde81f

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffffffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NOSOS

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NOSOS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NOSOS_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL_STACKIMMUNE

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 w3wp.exe+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wp.exe

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: w3wp

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bd0eb

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NOSOS_c0000005_w3wp.exe!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_NOSOS_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL_STACKIMMUNE_w3wp.exe


Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: yeah your worker process is being crashed, implement try catch blocks, try to get the error and logged in into either event handler or something else.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times for asking and then answering this question in such detail! You really helped me learn something valuable today; I really, really, really appreciate you had time to post all this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem.
Solution Steps:

- First I open ControlPanel> ActionCenter> Problem Reports
- I saw list of problems. and my IIS Crash problem.
- I entered item detail and save it is dumps.
- I downloaded Windbg then open this dump with it.
- and enter command `!analyze -v`

Windbg analized and show a text like this:

```
GetPageUrlData failed, server returned HTTP status 404
URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/w3wp_exe/7_5_7600_16385/4a5bd0eb/mscorwks_dll/2_0_50727_4927/4a27466f/c0000005/006be81f.htm?Retriage=1

FAULTING_IP: 
mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+24f
000007fe`f5dde81f 418b4514        mov     eax,dword ptr [r13+14h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef5dde81f (mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+0x000000000000024f)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000014
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000014

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000014

READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000014 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+24f
000007fe`f5dde81f 418b4514        mov     eax,dword ptr [r13+14h]

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

MANAGED_BITNESS_MISMATCH: 
Managed code needs matching platform of sos.dll for proper analysis. Use 'x64' debugger.

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fef3a0bf50 to 000007fef5dde81f

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffffffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NOSOS

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NOSOS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NOSOS_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL_STACKIMMUNE

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 w3wp.exe+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wp.exe

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: w3wp

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bd0eb

STACK_COMMAND:  ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NOSOS_c0000005_w3wp.exe!Unknown

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_NOSOS_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL_STACKIMMUNE_w3wp.exe

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:
Followup: MachineOwner

0:056> .exr 0xffffffffffffffff
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef5dde81f (mscorwks!COMCryptography::_GetKeyParameter+0x000000000000024f)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000014
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000014
```

So I added this code to Decrypt Method: **if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return String.Empty;**

```
public static string Decrypt(string value)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(EncryptionKey, EncryptionVector);

        // I control value
        **if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return String.Empty;**

        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        ...
    }
```

problem was solved.

Comment: Nice Solution ! This made our day !

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late, but I just debug a similar problem with WinDbg. I finally managed to find the cause of the problem.

It's a reported bug at microsoft:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/330926/cryptostream-flushfinalblock-fatal-on-64-bit-os-if-bytearray-is-null

I just add this to the discussion as a lead for others who search the web.

Answer (score 2):

Tess Ferrandez has some great tutorials and information on how to use DebugDiag and WinDbg to nail down why this is happening:

> [If it is broken, fix it you should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/)

There's also a lab to walk you through analysing worker process crashes:

> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 5: Crash](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025021552/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/03/05/net-debugging-demos-lab-5-crash.aspx)
>
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 2: Crash - Review](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105094450/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/02/11/net-debugging-demos-lab-2-crash-review.aspx)

Comment: Our web application worked without exceptions before we change projects 32 bit to 64 bit and we started to use server 2008 , IIS 7 in new Server.

Comment: @KaFKaFy - you should include this fairly important nugget of info on the question!

Comment: Sorry Kev, I did not know this changing when I wrote question :( Our team made this change.

Comment: @KaFKaFy - what did you find was to root cause?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same symptoms, and the real reason was that I accidentally created an infinite recursion, which in turn caused a stack overflow. Please note that you need to restart the app pool after correcting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET worker process is crashing with Access Violation. This is usually a result of dereferencing a NULL or an invalid pointer. Attempting to access a null reference in C# normally generates a managed exception which ASP.NET is capable of catching, I would assume that your web app is using COM interop or is invoking unmanaged (C++) code that crashes.

Unfortunately, that's about as much as we can tell you from the info above. You will need to debug your process to understand the exact cause of the crash.